# Finding the value for a date before a date and all the values for the dates after in pandas and find the function to calculate the integral

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have two dataframes one is a table with a date for some event (table_event), and the second a table with a value for multiple dates (table_values). I would like to create a third dataframe (table_all_dates) that combines the date of the events, the value and the date before the event in table_event and all the dates and values after the event in table_event.

After that I wish to link, using a linear regression, all events by row so I can find the integral. I can do it by hand, but I don't know to do it in more useful and quicker way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table_values = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'B'],
                             'date1': ['2014/05/05', '2014/05/05'], 'value1': [1, 5],
                             'date2': ['2014/05/16', '2014/05/16'], 'value2': [8, 7], 
                             'date3': ['2014/07/08', '2014/07/08'], 'value3': [np.nan, 2],
                             'date4': ['2014/07/15', '2014/07/15'], 'value4': [7, 6],
                             'date5': ['2014/07/18', '2014/07/18'], 'value5': [3, 1]
                            })

table_event = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'B'], 'date_event': ['2014/06/01', '2014/05/10']})


table_all_dates = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'B'], 
                                'date_event': ['2014/06/01', '2014/05/10'],

                                'date_before_event' : ['2014/05/16','2014/05/05'], 
                                'value_before_event' : [8,5],

                                'first_date_after_event' : ['2014/07/15','2014/05/16'],
                                'first_value_after_event' : [7,7],

                                'second_date_after_event' : ['2014/07/18','2014/07/08'],
                                'second_value_after_event' : [3,2],

                                'third_date_after_event' : ['null','2014/07/15'],
                                'third_value_after_event' : [np.nan,6],

                                'fourth_date_after_event' : ['null','2014/07/18'],
                                'fourth_value_after_event' : [np.nan,1]
                               })


(table_all_dates ['value_before_event']+table_all_dates ['first_value_after_event'])/2*(table_all_dates ['first_date_after_event']-table_all_dates ['date_before_event'])
```